# dynamic window manager (dwm): number of columns

Tags: dwm, tiling-wm

In [dwm](https://dwm.suckless.org/) typically I use one window in the master area (left) and all the others stacked on the right side. Once I accidentally hit Meta+I all windows get stacked in one single column (spanning full width of the screen). I don't know how to redo it, how to make 2 columns again? I remember once I found it after quite some research but I forgot again and now I could not find it. Also I remember one need to do the opposite key combination as many times as did Meta+i, e.g. if I pressed 5x Meta+i I need to do the key combination subject to this question 5 times to take effect. It looks like this is not dwm's built in feature, and could not find which patch provides it.

I have the dwm from Arch Linux repository.

*Note: I asked this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1347920/dynamic-window-manager-dwm-number-of-columns) one week ago but it got zero views so I came to the conclusion that's not the appropriate SE branch for the topic.*

Comment: put your config.h file

Comment: Ok, I found it. I have looked already at this file many times, I don't know how I missed it: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/deeenes/oeGagL Anyways useful to have it written here: by default Meta+i and Meta+d increase and decrease the number of windows in the master area, respectively. Thanks @Alexander!

Comment: @jasonwryan, SivaPrasath, sim: I posted the question on U&L 1 week later than SU, exactly because it's on-topic here and off-topic there, although based on the designated scope of the sites it should be the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the dwm manpage:

> **Mod1-i** Increase number of windows in master area.
>
> **Mod1-d**  Decrease number of windows in master area.

This feature does not come from a customisation, it's in the [default config.h](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/file/config.def.h.html#l69):

```
 { MODKEY,                       XK_i,      incnmaster,     {.i = +1 } },
 { MODKEY,                       XK_d,      incnmaster,     {.i = -1 } },
```